# Python numpy.polyfit uncertainties, unclear documentation

Tags: numpy, curve-fitting

I'm looking through the documentation of the polyfit routine and I found a possible contradiction. In the description of weights, it says:

> w |    array_like, shape (M,), optional Weights to apply to the
> y-coordinates of the sample points. For gaussian uncertainties, use
> 1/sigma **(not 1/sigma**2)**.

While in the section for cov it says:

> cov | bool or str, optional If given and not False, return not just the
> estimate but also its covariance matrix. By default, the covariance
> are scaled by chi2/dof, where dof = M - (deg + 1), i.e., the weights
> are presumed to be unreliable except in a relative sense and
> everything is scaled such that the reduced chi2 is unity. This scaling
> is omitted if cov='unscaled', as is relevant for the case that the
> **weights are 1/sigma**2**, with sigma known to be a reliable estimate of
> the uncertainty.

So I wanted to double-check if it is 1/sigma**2 or 1/sigma. I am assuming the latter.

Comment: `w` and `cov` are separate parameters.  It may help to look at the code as well as the docs.  `w` is used during fitting.  `cov` controls whether an additional `cov` matrix is returned, and whether is is scaled or not.  Do you understand what is meant by `gausian uncertainty` in this context?

Comment: @hpaulj From what I understand the gaussian uncertainty is what is used when you want to propagate known uncertainties on your data. (Which is what I am trying to do.) I have a certain uncertainty for each point on the fit and would like to propagate that through the fit. Using 1/sigma gives numbers that seem to make sense, if I square it they become huge.